# Why does printf cause a segfault in a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

My code takes a string of integers separated by spaces and builds a linked list out of them, except for -1. Why does printing `nextNode -> data` cause a segfault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node Node;
struct node {
  int data;
  Node *next;
};

void build_linked_list(Node **head_ptr) {
  char *string = malloc(1028);
  char *p = string, *found = string;
  Node *nextNode = NULL;
  if (fgets(string, 1028, stdin) != NULL) {
    while ((found = strsep(&p, " \n")) != NULL) {
      if (strcmp(found, "-1") == 1) {
        Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        node->data = atoi(found);
        node->next = nextNode;
        nextNode = node;
      }
    }
  }
  *head_ptr = nextNode;
  printf("%i\n", nextNode->data); //error here
  free(string);
}

int main() {
  Node *head = NULL;
  build_linked_list(&head);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You didn't check if `nextNode != NULL` before reading `nextNode->data`.

Comment: FYI strcmp returns non-zero (negative or positive values) if the two strings don't match, so you shouldn't test for the value 1.

Comment: The suspect I can see is `strcmp(found, "-1") == 1`. Do you *really* care about the lexicographic order of the string relative to "-1"? It you simply want to check it's not "-1", the condition should be `strcmp(found, "-1") != 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to print `nextNode->data` in any case, but what if `nextNode` is `NULL`? Trying to access a member of an invalid pointer will result in segmentation fault.

In details:

1. You initialize the pointer to `NULL`

   ```
   Node *nextNode = NULL;
   ```
2. You update the pointer, but **only under certain conditions**:

   ```
   if (fgets(string, 1028, stdin) != NULL) {
     while ((found = strsep(&p, " \n")) != NULL) {
       if (strcmp(found, "-1") == 1) {
         /* ... */
         nextNode = node;
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. You print the field

   ```
    printf("%i\n", nextNode->data); //error here
   ```

   but if the conditions aren't met, the pointer might still be NULL

To solve the issue, check the pointer before dereferencing it:

```
if( nextNode )
{
    printf("%i\n", nextNode->data);
}
else
{
    printf("NULL nextnode\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't check if `nextNode != NULL` before reading `nextNode->data`.

[strcmp(3) - Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html)

> strcmp() returns an integer indicating the result of the comparison,
> as follows:
>
> ```
>    · 0, if the s1 and s2 are equal;
>
>    · a negative value if s1 is less than s2;
>
>    · a positive value if s1 is greater than s2.
> ```

What is returned from `strcmp()` when the two strings differ need not be `1`, so `strcmp(found, "-1") == 1` is a wrong expression to check if `found` is not `-1`.

It seems `strcmp()` in your environment is returning things other than `1` and no insertion is performed, so `NULL` is dereferencing at `nextNode->data`, invoking Segmentation Fault.

Try this:

```
void build_linked_list(Node **head_ptr) {
  char *string = malloc(1028);
  char *p = string, *found = string;
  Node *nextNode = NULL;
  if (fgets(string, 1028, stdin) != NULL) {
    while ((found = strsep(&p, " \n")) != NULL) {
      /* use != 0 to check string inequility and avoid processing empty string */
      if (strcmp(found, "-1") != 0 && strcmp(found, "") != 0) {
        Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        node->data = atoi(found);
        node->next = nextNode;
        nextNode = node;
      }
    }
  }
  *head_ptr = nextNode;
  if (nextNode != NULL) { /* check if nextNode is not NULL */
    printf("%i\n", nextNode->data); //error here
  }
  free(string);
}
```